# Changing password of the signed in user in code igniter

Tags: codeigniter

I am working on Code Igniter and stuck in a place where I need to change the password of a signed-in user. I need help in picking up the user id of the signed-in user and through it I want to update the password of that user.

The following are the images of controller and models created of the project respectively.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hey Sanyam. Welcome to stackoverflow. You would get help more likely if you share what you have done so far to solve the problem. Also it appears your images do not exist.

Comment: where is your images ?

Comment: Remove some unneeded text.

Comment: @AliKanat Thank you Ali for taking out your precious time to help me with my issues but after more R&D I finally founded the solution. I was not able to pick the session Id earlier of the logged in user but lately I was able to do that. Still thanks for your kind response and images are attached with the query. IDK why its not visible.

Comment: @H45H images are attached already but IDK why it is not visible. Still thanks for stepping in to help me out.

Comment: @rlandster Thanks for the feedback mate I will surely keep it in mind to remove unneeded texts and to follow the coding standards wisely.

Answer (score 1):

```
Create html link:
<a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>user/changePassword"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>Change password</a>
```

---

```
Create user controller:
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class User extends CI_Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        // Load form helper library
        $this->load->helper('form');

        // Load form validation library
        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        // Load session library
        $this->load->library('session');

        $this->load->model('Data_model');
    }

    public function changePassword()
    {
        $web = array();
        $web['title'] = 'Change password';
        $web['content'] = 'web/password';

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('old_password', 'Old password', 'required|callback_check_password');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('new_password', 'New password', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('confirm_password', 'Confirm password', 'required|matches[new_password]');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
            $this->load->view('web_template',$web);
        } else {

            $id = $this->user_id;

            $data = array(
                'user_password' => $this->input->post('new_password'),
            );

            $this->Common_model->Data_model('user_login', $data, 'id', $id);
            $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', 'Password changed Successfully');

            redirect('user/changePassword');
        }

    }

    function check_password($password) {        
        if($this->user_id)
            $id = $this->user_id;
        else
            $id = '';

        $result = $this->Data_model->check_user_password($id, $password);
        if($result > 0)
            $response = true;
        else {
            $this->form_validation->set_message('check_password', 'Old password is wrong');
            $response = false;
        }

        return $response;
    }
}
```

---

```
Change password html page in view:
<section class="content">
    <div class="box">
        <div class="box-header with-border">
            <h3 class="box-title"><?php echo $title; ?></h3>
            <div class="box-tools pull-right">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="collapse" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Collapse">
                <i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php 
            $attributes = array('class' => 'form-horizontal', 'id' => 'changePassword');
            echo form_open('user/changePassword', $attributes); 
        ?>
        <div class="box-body">
            <?php if (!empty($this->session->flashdata('msg'))) : ?>
                <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable alertDiv"> <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('msg'); ?> </div>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-md-2 control-label">Old password</label>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <input type="password" name="old_password" value="<?php echo (isset($form_data) ? $form_data->old_password : set_value('old_password')); ?>" class="form-control" id="old_password" placeholder="Old password">
                            <?php echo form_error('old_password', '<div class="error">', '</div>'); ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-md-2 control-label">New password</label>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <input type="password" name="new_password" value="<?php echo (isset($form_data) ? $form_data->new_password : set_value('new_password')); ?>" class="form-control" id="new_password" placeholder="New password" autocomplete="off">
                            <?php echo form_error('new_password', '<div class="error">', '</div>'); ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-md-2 control-label">Confirm Password</label>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <input type="password" name="confirm_password" value="<?php echo (isset($form_data) ? $form_data->confirm_password : set_value('confirm_password')); ?>" class="form-control" id="confirm_password" placeholder="Confirm Password" autocomplete="off">
                            <?php echo form_error('confirm_password', '<div class="error">', '</div>'); ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-offset-5" style="margin-top: 10px;">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php form_close(); ?>
    </div>
    <!-- /.box -->
</section>
```

---

```
Create Data_model in model add this function:
// Update data to table
    public function update($table, $data, $primaryfield, $id)
    {
        $this->db->where($primaryfield, $id);
        $q = $this->db->update($table, $data);
        return $q;
    }
//Check the old password:
function check_user_password($id = '', $password) {
        $this->db->where('user_password', $password);
        $this->db->where('id', $id);

        return $this->db->get('user_login')->num_rows();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a ton brother for giving out such a great help although I was able to make it on my own way and with different and basic methods but still I appreciate for your help and efforts. I got to learn few things and methods to solve this issue. Will be seeking you out in future for more help. Stay Connected